# Why am I getting negative components with my custom NIPALS algorithm

Tags: python, pca, data-transformation, partial-least-squares

I've recently been learning about the Nonlinear Iterative Partial Least Squares (NIPALS) algorithm for computing the principal components of a dataset. I am trying to code a NIPALS class from scratch in Python to get a more intuitive understanding of the algorithm:

```
class NIPALS:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Attributes:
        - self.U: after fitting returns a matrix of
          (n_components, n_features).
    
        - self.Y: after fitting returns a matrix of 
          (n_samples, n_transformed_features).
    
        - self.R1: after fitting returns a list of
          rank 1 matrices. 
      
        - self.iterations: after fitting returns an
          integer indicating how many iterations the 
          fit took to converge.
        """
        self.U = []
        self.Y = []
        self.R1 = []
    
        self.n_loops = 0
    
    def vector_len(self, a: np.ndarray): 
        return np.sqrt(np.dot(a, a))

    def normalize_vector(self, v):
        return v*(1/vector_len(v))
    
    def converge(self, t, A):
        # step 2: compute the principal component
        p = ((t.T@A)/(t.T@t)).T
    
        # step 3: normalize the principal component
        p_norm = self.normalize_vector(p.flatten()).reshape(-1,1)
    
        # step 4: project the data onto the principal component
        t = A@p_norm
    
        return t, p_norm
    
    def fit(self, A):
        # step 1: grab the first column vector from the data matrix
        t = A[:,0].reshape(-1,1)
    
        # step 5: compare t from the start of the iteration to t from
        # the end of the iteration; continue until convergence
        while np.all(self.converge(t, A)[0] != t):
            t, p_norm = self.converge(t, A)

        # append the pc and the coordinates
        self.U.append(p_norm.T)
        self.Y.append(t)
    
        # count the loops
        self.n_loops+=1
    
        # terminate when n_loops = n_features
        if self.n_loops == A.shape[1]:
            self.U = np.row_stack(self.U) 
            self.Y = np.column_stack(nipals.Y)
            return
        else:
            # step 6: deflate the data matrix
            r1 = t@p_norm.T
            E = A-r1
            self.R1.append(r1)
        
            # step 7: restart the loop
            self.fit(E)
```

I am testing this class out on the [Breast Cancer Wisconsin dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/17/breast+cancer+wisconsin+diagnostic) and comparing it to the result I get from using PCA class from sklearn. The results are nearly identical however, some components that I get from my class are the opposite sign, examples:

[image]

[image]

There doesn't seem to be a discernible pattern regarding which components are the opposite sign. Can anybody help me understand what's going on here? I know that sklearn uses the SVD to compute the PCs. Is this difference due to the difference in methods?

Any answers are much appreciated!